# Solving the differential equation $ y-\frac{dy}{dx}- x (\frac{dy}{dx})^2=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Must I reduce this to clairaut's form to solve this? If so, just pointers to reduce to clairaut's is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a rather difficult one. This is a [d'Alembert equation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/dAlembertsEquation.html) (Sometimes also known as Lagrange's Equation). Thus, one should write:
$$y=x\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2+\frac{dy}{dx}$$
Differentiate both sides w.r.t $x$:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2+\frac{d^2 y}{dx^2}+2x\frac{dy}{dx}\cdot \frac{d^2 y}{dx^2}$$
Thus, one may write:
$$y'=(y')^2+y''+2xy'\cdot y''$$
This can be factored and be written as:
$$y''=\frac{y'-(y')^2}{1+2xy'}$$
Now, we substitute $v=y'$. Hence:
$$\frac{dv}{dx}=\frac{v-v^2}{1+2xv}$$
Taking the reciprocal on both sides:
$$\frac{dx}{dv}=\frac{1+2xv}{v-v^2}$$
Thus, one must then solve the first-order linear ordinary differential equation and solve for $x(v)$.
$$\frac{dx}{dv}-\frac{2v}{v-v^2}x=\frac{1}{v-v^2}$$
$$\frac{dx}{dv}+\frac{2}{v-1}x=\frac{1}{v-v^2} \tag{2}$$
This can be solved using an [integrating factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrating_factor).

---

Note that you may not be able to find an explicit solution for $y(x)$, however you should be able to find two explicit solutions for $x(y)$.

Comment: Thanks, The IF is $\frac {v-1} {v} $